# How can Nextcloud data be backed up and restored independently? (Versioning / Snapshots)

Tags: backup, database, snapshot, restore, nextcloud

Whenever multiple users are interacting with a Nextcloud installation, there is a possibility of error. Potentially, a family member may delete an old picture or a co-worker might accidentally tick off a task or calendar event, resulting in issues for other users.

When full filesystem snapshots or backups of the whole Nextcloud directory are available, they can be used to restore an old state of the entire server. This is fine in case of a complete system crash.

However, it becomes an issue if the problem is only noticed after a while and in the mean time, users have modified other data. Then, a choice must be made between rescuing old data and destroying all progress or keeping the current state.

The [Nextcloud documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/maintenance/restore.html) only describes a way to restore the entire installation.

Is there a way to more intelligently back up all Nextcloud data automatically (files, messages, calendars, tasks, etc.) so that it can be restored independently? (Maybe even in an online state?)

Answer (score 0):

Restoring an online state would indeed require a full disk backup (which of course could be done incrementally).

Of course, the things that actually change through user interaction are

1. the database (containing all user info, file metadata, permissions…)
2. the data store
3. nextcloud itself (as it might get updated).

We can "solve" 3. by simply requiring a full backup of all three every time you backup nextcloud (database formats might not be backwards compatible).

In a typical containerized nextcloud setup, you'd have two or three containers:

1. the database container "DB", which needs to be started first (typically running postgresql)
2. the container actually running nextcloud "NC", which connects to the database in DB, and has the data directory mounted as external volume "V"
3. (a reverse proxy to allow hiding nextcloud behind HTTPS easily, and to decouple SSL certificate handling from the nextcloud container)

Now, a regular backup would consist of

1. stopping nextcloud, or at least freezing NC, or stopping NC alltogether
2. making a backup of V (which can be nicely and incrementally – any modern backup utility will do that),
3. telling your database to make a backup (`pg_backup_start`), which will start the backup in a consistent state (the database makes sure new operations don't influence the state that gets backed up)
4. right after initiating the 3. step, to restore functionality, restart nextcloud (or thaw, or restart NC)
5. make the database write the dump to a file (`pg_backup_stop`); make sure you know which data backup belongs to which database backup (should be clear from time and date)

Generally, since the actual nextcloud container is not going to be very large, anyways, since it contains neither the data itself nor the database, it would also make sense to just save that along with the data and database backups.

Restoring can be done then on a completely different (virtual) machine, by spinning up a copy of the database container, restoring the database backup, in the meantime unpacking the data backup, then after the database has started starting the nextcloud container with the data mounted.

---

As a matter of fact, since container runtimes (podman, but also Docker) allow you to do independent networking, you can have as many database servers running in parallel as you want; together with a filesystem that you use for the data volume that supports snapshots (ZFS, btrfs, and things like LVM snapshots+XFS thin provisioning, bcachefs…), you could then explore the old state in parallel to your current state, without them interfering.

Comment: The MySQL or MariaDB databases are the recommended database engines for nextcloud, not postgres. ( https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/20/admin_manual/configuration_database/linux_database_configuration.html ). The docker hub's docker-compose example uses a mariadb as well (https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/), maybe OP isn't using PG.

Comment: huh, my instances all use postgresql. Really shouldn't make a difference for smaller installations (reading up in forums seems to reveal that the answer to why they prefer mysql/mariadb over postgres is mostly "in the very large case, we saw better performance (state: 2017), and we know mysql better"

Answer (score 0):

**Calendar, Messages, etc**
**In theory** a database dump should create calendar entries etc. with one ore more INSERT query/ies.
You'd only need find the correct INSERT/s and try to reinsert them/it in the current database. (I'd backup the current state before trying that out)

In my oppinion the trashbin & versions offer good options for restoring data for the users.

**Files & Trashbin**
By default the trashbin is activated. When a file is deleted by a user, it goes to the trash. You can specify the age to keep the files in the trash in `config/config.php` with the entry: `trashbin_retention_obligation' => 'auto, 128',` (check the manual for details). However if the available space/user quota goes below 50% it might get cleaned up earlier, or if adming is running `occ trashbin:expire;occ trashbin:cleanup` manually. (or by the users choice)
I don't use the calendar, maybe deleted calendar entries end in trash as well and could be restored - I don't know.

**Files & Version**
Another thing is the "version nextcloud app" which adds the option to restore older version of a file. The age could be set with   `'versions_retention_obligation' => 'auto, 128',` in `config.php`. Enable it in the nextcloud apps section. I haven't used this app, should be like shadow copies.

**Restoring single files**
As long as you're not using encryption, and use only local accounts, user data  is stored in the `nextcloud/data/username` directory. If you're connected to active directory / openldap, the directory is `nextcloud/data/uuid` the uuid could be resolved in the database. (`SELECT ldap_dn FROM oc_ldap_user_mapping WHERE owncloud_name='$U_ID'`)
Files can be restored manually from the backuped user directory and copied into the current user data directory. Make sure to scan all files with `occ files:scan` afterwards.

If encryption is enabled - :) good luck.